# Copy columns C:D to first empty cell in column A

Tags: excel, vba

I appreciate there have been various posts on this and i have found what has been confirmed as a solution, however i am hoping someone may be kind enough to advise how i get it work with my code. I have been using record macro function as I cant write VBA. In my example, i have copied column C and D, then scrolled down to first empty cell in column A and pasted. However when repeating this, the first empty cell in column A will vary. I have kept in ref to cell A302 in code but marked it so that a comment, just purely to illustrate how it looks prior to me trying to amend.
I have used solution i found elsewhere on this site, but i get an error and I have no idea what to tweak in order for it to work. Ive desperately tried a couple of things but no joy.

```
Range("C1:D1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
'Range("A303").Select
***Range("A" & Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row).Select***
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I also tried

```
Range("C1:D1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
'Range("A303").Select
***Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select***
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Full script is

```
    Sub Create_Collapsed_Group_Tab_7()
'
' Create_Collapsed_Group_Tab_7 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("CYBcollapseinputfile").Select
    Sheets("CYBcollapseinputfile").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-2]:C[-1],RC[-2])"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3]:C[-2],RC[-2])"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
    Range("C1:E1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:E" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("E:E"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("C:C"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("D:D"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:F")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("F1:F3").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F1:F" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=IF(" & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,""""))))<>""""," & Chr(10) & "MIN(" & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP" & _
        "(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C5:R1C5,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C5:R1C5,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C5:R1C5,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C5:R1C5,9999)),RC[-1])" & _
        ""
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
        "=IF(" & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,""""))))<>""""," & Chr(10) & "MIN(" & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C6:R1C6,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP" & _
        "(RC2,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C8:R1C8,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC2,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C8:R1C8,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C2:R1C2,R[-1]C8:R1C8,9999)," & Chr(10) & "XLOOKUP(RC4,R[-1]C4:R1C4,R[-1]C8:R1C8,9999)),RC[-2])" & _
        ""
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C1:D1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A303").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Cells.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("B:B"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
        :=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:D")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), _
        Header:=xlNo
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=TRIM(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C[-2],C[-1]=RC[-1])))"
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TRIM(CONCAT(TEXTJOIN(""|"",TRUE,RC[1]:RC[23]),""|""))"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
     Columns("B:Z").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$571").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Sheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Select
    Sheets("CYBcollapseinputfile (2)").Name = "CYBcollapseinputfilegrouped"
    Sheets("Macro Buttons and Actions").Select
    MsgBox ("Collapse API Pairs Grouped")
End Sub
```

Comment: It will be worth your time reviewing this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?r=Saves_AllUserSaves   If you can apply some of the suggestions there it will be worth the effort.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution did work. For anyone looking to do same as me and have as part of a larger script rather stand alone, it looked as follows in my solution

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range 
Set ws = ActiveSheet 
Set rng = ws.Range("C1:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) 
With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 
   .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out: you can assign the range value directly, without needing a copy/paste

```vb
Sub CopyCDtoA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific sheet
    
    'range to be copied
    Set rng = ws.Range("C1:D" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)  'next empty cell in ColA
        .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 'copy values
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply, however as what i provided is a very small section of a larger script, i am really struggling to figure out how to insert what you have provided.
I tried to overwrite section where i select columns C and D and then paste to A303 but it doesn't work, I hope you don't mind me providing full script so that you may advise? I am not looking for full script to be rewritten, just how i paste columns C and D into first empty cell in row A. 
I tried to provide full script but too long by 8000 chars.

Comment: My code is only wrapped in a sub so it can be run stand-alone for testing/demo purposes.  You'd replace the code you posted above with what's in my sub.

Comment: Thanks for looking and your support. Been working on this workbook since 7am, going to give it a rest and try again tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.